# How do you prevent arrow up/down default behaviour in a TextField?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I am making a input field for keywords, and while the users writing I'm displaying suggestions for keyword on a list underneath the caret position.
The input field is single line, so I am using the arrow up/down key to select a suggestion and Enter to insert it.
And it's mostly working, with the big exception that the up/down key also changes the caret position to the begining/ending of the `TextField`.

I've tried using `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` in the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event listener that I also use to change the selected suggestion, but that does not change anything.
I checked the carret has not yet moved when `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event is fired, bu visually I can see that it is being move before key is released (key up).

I could just save the caret position, and then reset af the default behaviour. But that would properly involve some hack-like code using a timer.

So does anyone know how to prevent the default behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't prevent it, but you can reverse it. To do that you add to handlers with different priorities to the same event - KeyboardEvent.DOWN. One will execute before the TextField's , and save selection indexes and the other after, restoring them. Working code follows:

```
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import mx.controls.TextInput;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class FooledTextInput extends TextInput
    {
        private var ssi : int = 0;
        private var sei : int = 0;

        public function FooledTextInput()
        {
            super();

            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onBeforeKeyDown, false, 10000);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onAfterKeyDown, false, -10000);
        }

        private function onBeforeKeyDown(e : KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                ssi = this.selectionBeginIndex;
                sei = this.selectionEndIndex;
            }   
        } 

        private function onAfterKeyDown(e : KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                this.setSelection(ssi, sei);
            }   
        } 
    }
```

You might want better names for ssi (selection start index) and sei (selection end index), I was to lazy to find some.
I think this solution was based on a post of Alex Harui, I don't remember exactly, but he's got a lot of good Flex related stuff on his blog.

**UPDATE:** For the spark TextInput, preventing is not only possible, it is really easy. All you need to do is catch the event in the capture phase and stopping propagation. Code:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import spark.components.TextInput;

    public class HackedTextInput extends TextInput
    {
        public function HackedTextInput()
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onBeforeKeyDown, true);
        }

        private function onBeforeKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }   
        }  
    }
}
```

Note the last parameter in the addEventListener call, which is set to true in order for the handler to be called in the capture phase. Sadly this solution doesn't work for the mx TextInput, only for the spark one.

Comment: I am making this in Flash, so I am using a TextField instead of a TextInput.
I can not get this to work properly, the problem seems to be that the onAfterKeyDown is called before the default behavior.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the onAfterKeyDown with low priority? Try even a lower number than -10000, though I don't think that would be the issue.

Comment: It's weird that it wouldn't work. Try adding the listeners on the component holding the TextField. Either have one component for each TextField, or one for all of them. The reason it should work that way is, because of the bubbling of the events, the handler for the TextField is triggered first, and then those of it's parent. And for the same reason you might want to actually add onBeforeKeyDown listener on the TextField to store the values, and onAfterKeyDown on its parent to restore them. That should do the trick.

Comment: Ahh, of cause. Clever thinking with bubbling. I will give it a go.

Comment: It still wont work, I even tried listening on the to resture the value. But when the KEY_DOWN event is fired on the stage, the values have not changed yet.
Damn Adobe and their use of magic in their components...

Comment: This does not work.  It seems like the TextField just sucks up the Keyboard events and does it's own thing, after any custom handlers have run, so that you cannot intercept and prevent the default behavior of any key strokes.  This sucks, because it adds random line breaks at the end of the last paragraph, and when you delete them with the delete key, no change event fires, and there's no workaround to fix this buggy behavior, because you can't intercept and prevent the default behavior of keystrokes.

Comment: The code works as posted with Flex 4.1 sdk, the mx TextInput, not the spark one. The spark TextInput uses different selection methods. It should also work with the latest Flex 3 sdk, unless you're modifying the selection through some other means.
<br>
@Triynko As stated, this code, doesn't prevent the behavior, it reverts it. The end effect is the desired one, but the way it is done is "hackish", exactly because you can't prevent the textField handlers from being executed.

Answer (score 4):

I have posted a workaround for this problem here :
[AS3: setSelection Up Arrow Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928474/as3-setselection-up-arrow-override/6725314#6725314)

Comment: second that. worked for me with preventing Up Arrow behaviour on an actionscript-only textfield

Answer (score 1):

The solution by bug-a-lot is intriguing - I didnlt think to use priorities. Instead, I made use of the different phases of the event process. The problem for me was to decide whether the arrow keys should advance or retreat one character within the given text field, or jump to the next or previous field in the form.

First, I override the stage's event handling for the keys:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, typing);
// Sneak in before the normal processing handles right and left arrow keystrokes.
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pretyping, true, 10);
```

Note that I will process each key twice - before the system does it's wizardry (pretyping is called before the KEY_DOWN) so I can see where the caret is before Flash moves it, and after the system handles it (with typing, called after KEY_UP).

```
/** Capture prior state of text field so we can later tell if user should tab to next field or previous field. */
private function pretyping(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var keyString:String = Configuration.getKeyString(evt);
    if (isFocusInTextBox()) {
        var tf:TextField = getFocus() as TextField;
        capturePhaseCaret = tf.caretIndex;
    }
}
```

getKeyString is a method of mine - all it does is turn those codes into convenient mnemonics. And isFocusInTextBox is a call to my focus manager - I replaced the standard focus manager to overcome other Flash issues. I just need to know if the thing is a text field or not.

Next I have to process the key after Flash has already moved the caret and maybe even jumped to a new field, and by looking at the prior state, decide what Flash did and undo it and then do what ought to happen. My function "typing" has a lot of stuff not needed for this discussion, but the important thing it does is call allowKeyMapping. allowKeyMapping decides if the user entered forward arrow (or down arrow) from the last character position in the text field, or entered backward arrow from the beginning. If so, "typing" will tab to the next or previous field, respectively.

```
    /** Prefer default behavior and do not allow certain kestrokes to be reinterpreted by key mappings, such as left and right cursor keys in text boxes. */
    private function allowKeyMapping(keyString:String) {
        var allow:Boolean;
        // If focus is in a text field, allow right arrow to advance to next field only if caret is at end of text.
        // Conversely, allow left arrow to back up to previous field only if caret is at beginning of text.
        // The trick is that the normal processing of keystrokes by TextFields occurs before this method is called,
        // so we need to know the caret position from before the key was pressed, which we have stored in capturePhaseCaret, set in pretyping.
        if (isDragging) {
            allow = false;
        }
        else if (isFocusInTextBox()) {
            var tf:TextField = getFocus() as TextField;
            if (keyString == Configuration.LEFT_CURSOR_KEY) {
                allow = tf.caretIndex == 0 && capturePhaseCaret == 0;
            }
            else if (keyString == Configuration.RIGHT_CURSOR_KEY) {
                allow = tf.caretIndex == tf.text.length && capturePhaseCaret == tf.text.length;
            }
            else {
                allow = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            allow = true;
        }
        return allow;
    }
```

I am sorry I do not have a compact example prepared. I just thought it important to emphasize that you can get around Flash's penchant for doing things for you whether you want them to happen or not.

Comment: I have something similar to this now, but when using the KEY_UP, you can sometimes see the caret jump a bit around.
So I would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some flick effect with the bug-a-lot's solution.

There is a working solution and good trick using `stage.invalidate()` and stage's `Event.RENDER` described here :

[AS3: setSelection Up Arrow Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928474/as3-setselection-up-arrow-override)

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround for that problem. I'm sure there is a better way but it would probably require extending the TextInput control.

```
private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == flash.ui.Keyboard.UP)
    {
        var begin:int = textinput.selectionBeginIndex;
        var end:int = textinput.selectionEndIndex;
        textinput.setSelection(begin,end);
    }
}
```

Not sexy but it works.

Comment: That does not work for me. I would properly have to save the positions and the apply them af the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

by default event are priority 0 on UIComponent
so you can always stop stop something to happen, here you prevent all KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN

```
yourObject.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _preventDefault, false, 1, true );
private function _preventDefault(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```