# Is there any way of disabling the "Page Down/Page Up" keys for a textField in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

A little problem occurs when the Page Down key is pressed on a multiline textfield, in my case an input type textfield.

The problem is that after pressing Page Down, it seems to add an extra empty line at the end of the text.

I would like to know if there is a possibility of actually disabling Page Down and Page Up keys functionality for a textfield as i don't really need them and this little pesky problem really bugs me.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try using keyboard events.  Make a keyboard event that test against the page_down key, and in the constructor code of the conditional statement, say `event.preventDefault()` which would prevent whatever page_down key does.

Comment: Thank you for your input!
I did that, and when i hit page down the caret still moves to the end of the text, enter still creates a new line of text and so on :\

inputText.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handler);

private function handler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

    e.preventDefault();
}

Comment: Thanks again for your help, i found the workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928474/as3-setselection-up-arrow-override/6725314#6725314

this works exactly as i needed :)
i can go to sleep peacefully now